# Changing main url in Hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

This is the code repository: https://github.com/AJuliette/portfolio

I added this theme: https://github.com/kishaningithub/hugo-creative-portfolio-theme (manually, because it was pre-modules). The index url is forced to '/portfolio' and I can't change it to '/'.

I tried [the solutions listed in an issue of the original repository](https://github.com/kishaningithub/hugo-creative-portfolio-theme/issues/76) but they don't work.